# How could I downsize CNN?

Tags: neural-networks, convolution

Let's take a CNN with an input of size (512, 512) and an output of the same size.

Now imagine I want to feed an image of size (256, 256) to the network. Would it be possible to do so without upscaling the image? The purpose to do that is to reduce inference time. Would it be possible to freeze a part of the network or anything else to make it possible?